# Derive the result of a formula for each combination of three input parameters

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I have been struggling with an issue in R and have tried google and the search function, but have not found a solution.

I would like to do the following:

Derive the interest rate payment revenue for a set of combinations of duration, amount and interest rate. The set are defined as follows:

1. Amount (a) = 1,000 - 25,000 with intervals of 100
2. Duration (d) = 12 - 60 (months) with intervals of 6
3. Interest Rate (i) 0.00 - 0.015 with intervals of 0.001

The formula goes as follows: w = a*d*(((i/12)*(1+(i/12))^(d))/((1+(i/12))^(d)-1)) - a
, where w is the interest rate payment.

My solution was to calculate w with three 'for' loops and save the data with the 'rbind' command. Sadly this does not work for me:

```
result = NULL

amount <- seq(1000, 25000, by=100)

duration <- seq(12, 60, by=6)

interest <- seq(0, 0.015, by=0.0001)

for (d in duration){
    for (a in amount){
      for (i in interest){
        w = a*d*(((i/12)*(1+(i/12))^(d))/((1+(i/12))^(d)-1)) - a
      }
    }
}

result = rbind(d, data.frame(d, a, i, w))
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I kind of on the right track? The output should be a list with all possible combinations and the 'w' value. Alternatively, the output could be a list with all possible combinations for a certain value for w.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Best, Alex

Comment: As is you'll need to save the w in the for loop into some data structure. Right now you're generating a bunch of values of w, but just constantly overwriting it without storing it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to tweak your current approach:

```
amount <- seq(1000, 25000, by=100)
duration <- seq(12, 60, by=6)
interest <- seq(0, 0.015, by=0.0001)
result <- expand.grid(amount, duration, interest)
names(result) <- c("amount", "duration", "interest")

for(i in 1:nrow(result)){
  result$w[i] <- result$amount[i]*result$duration[i]*(((result$interest[i]/12)*(1+(result$interest[i]/12))^(result$duration[i]))/((1+(result$interest[i]/12))^(result$duration[i])-1)) - result$amount[i]
}
```

However, `data.table` is about a million times faster:

```
library("data.table")
amount <- seq(1000, 25000, by=100)
duration <- seq(12, 60, by=6)
interest <- seq(0, 0.015, by=0.0001)
result <- expand.grid(amount, duration, interest)

setDT(result)
setnames(result, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"), c("amount", "duration", "interest"))
result[, w := amount*duration*(((interest/12)*(1+(interest/12))^(duration))/((1+(interest/12))^(duration)-1)) - amount]
```

Comment: Wow, did not know about `expand.grid`. Awesome.

Comment: can you pass the function to the dataframe, as you do with data.table, to see speed gains.

Comment: @user20650:  `result$w <- result$amount*result$duration*(((result$interest/12)*(1+(result$interest/12))^(result$duration))/((1+(result$interest/12))^(result$duration)-1)) - result$amount
`

Comment: I'm not sure what the `data.table` part here. You just used the fact that `*`, `+`, ```\``` and etc. are vectorized. On the contrary, the only place where you could actually use `data.table` (`CJ` instead of `expand.grid`) you actually haven't used it. I'm confused.

Comment: @DavidArenburg True, it's not needed in this case. Wanted to give a solution that he could build upon for any type of operation.